# Installing Oracle Database and can’t find “Workgroup Manager” in Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

Tags: macos

I just started to work with Mac and I’m trying to install Oracle Database using [the instructions at this link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B13954_01/toc.htm). [Section 6 of this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B13954_01/toc.htm#BEBGIIHE) says that some groups should be constructed using “Workgroup Manager” which is located in `/Applications/Server/Workgroup Manager`. But in the `Applications` folder there is no Server application.

Can anybody tell me what should I do and how can I create groups?

Answer (score 1):

You say this:

> [Section 6 of this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B13954_01/toc.htm#BEBGIIHE) says that some groups should be
>   constructed using “Workgroup Manager” which is located in
>   `/Applications/Server/Workgroup Manager`. But in the `Applications`
>   folder there is no Server application.

First, remember those instructions date back to December 2004; screenshot below:

[image]

So 11+ years later, some specifics won’t be valid or useful. But you can work around it if you try. Read on.

And yes, those instructions are asking for you to use “Workgroup Manager” and that is not a part of the normal/basic core Mac OS X operating system. That is a part of Mac OS X Server which is the server software suite that is installed. And since you are using a normal/basic Mac OS X operating system install, there is no way you will find “Workgroup Manager” anywhere.

That said you ask this:

> Can anybody tell me what should I do and how can I create groups?

Like I said at the outset, specifics in an old document like that are out of date but you can work around it. According to [this official Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202498):

> Workgroup Manager is not included with OS X Server. When upgrading to
>   OS X Mountain Lion or later, the installer removes Workgroup Manager.
>
> To administer iOS and OS X systems, use Profile Manager included with
>   OS X Server. Profile Manager delivers configuration profiles and
>   Mobile Device Management (MDM) for Macs running OS X Mountain Lion,
>   Lion, and iOS devices.

So basically one route to doing this is to purchase and install the modern [Mac OS X server software from the Apple app store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-server/id883878097?mt=12). It costs $19.99 and is fairly easy to use. But if this is a personal computer or a test machine where you don’t need additional server capabilities, that server software package might be overkill.

Instead you can create users and groups easily by just going to “System Preferences… -> Users & Groups” unlocking the small administrator lock in the lower left-hand corner if you need to, and then click the `+` item near the bottom of the user list on the left-hand side. The default `+` action is to create a new standard user but if you click that “New Account:” pulldown list you will see the “Group” option right at the bottom; see picture below:

[image]

Create the new group there and you should be good to go.

But that said, be cautious about those Oracle Database installation instructions for Mac OS X. Like I said, they date back to 2004 and 11+ years is a fairly long time in the world of step-by-step instructions.